Ship sinking prevention device using foam?
I hope that this is the correct StackExchange site for my question.
My question is based on three independent facts:

There is a story that a patent on lifting sunken ships using a foamed polymer (such as foamed polystyrene) was not granted because a similar method was already "described" in a comic book for children.

I saw some TV documentaries about different ship accidents (often small fishing vessels) where a ship sunk and not all persons could be rescued.

On a construction site, I could see that you can get a very large volume of construction foam out of a relatively small can.


My question:
Would it be possible to build a device for ships that contains a lot of construction foam or a similar material so that the hull of the vessel is filled with that foam when an accident happens and the ship is going to sink?

Self sealing hulls are possible. But, generally ships dont sink because of leaks, they sink because of various catasthrophic failures.

How would you get the cargo out one all available space is used for foam?

Self-righting vessels exist and are in use. You should check them out.

@SolarMike When thinking about this, I was aware that the ship and the cargo would be lost because it would be nearly impossible to remove the foam again. However, my main focus was saving the lives of the people on board.

Lots of stuff is possible. Part of what you will run into is how construction spray foam (mostly polyurethane) fares when sprayed out into pressurized sea water. Polystyrene would be better but forming low density polystyrene creation generally requires a low pressure atmosphere loaded with steam. I suspect a large compressed gas system might fare better in terms of cost, especially if the same could provide utility as powering pneumatic subsystems.

Would it be possible? almost always has a yes answer ... it is a somewhat useless question

It would probably be easier to deploy big inflatable cushions, possibly on the outside, a bit like airbags. Most likely, that would more be a thing for smaller boats, a bit like parachutes for small airplanes.

And of course, many unsinkable boat designs have foamed-out double hulls already. I suppose the foam is also an element of structural stability between two rigid but thin skins.

It's a common design feature for the bow and stern of canoes to come pre-filled with foam.  Makes them effectively unsinkable.

Using expanding foam to lift a ship basically won't work because the pressure generated by the foam isn't sufficient to overcome the pressure at depth. The expansion ratio would be tiny and the density would be about the same as the water displaced. There are "foams" (syntactic foam) that are ridiculously strong, but they are also quite dense and crazy expensive. Deep dive submersibles use them because they are slightly better than the buoyancy diesel fuel tanks used on things like the Trieste II (aka DSV 1).
In order for anything like this to work, they must deploy early enough to prevent the vessel from sinking in the first place.
Small craft sold in the US, such as runabouts, are required to be unsinkable. They are tested. They mostly have expanded foam poured into compartments during assembly.
On medium sized sailing vessels with ballasted keels, it is possible to use foam in several ways to prevent a complete capsize. There are boats that have foam in the top of their masts to prevent them turning upside down. This is a scale thing, though. It becomes less practical as boats get large. And adding weight to the top of the mast is the last place you want to put it in a boat like Bayesian which was already topheavy. But it can work on a 40' cruiser. Foam can be incorporated into the structural panels. This is one of the real advantages of cored composite construction. It lowers the density of the fabrication. Many vessels are designed with sealed compartments intended for buoyancy. But over time, owners tend to cut access holes in them and use the space for storage. It's also difficult to predict the sailing weight of a boat. I crewed on a boat that the designer intended to weight between 22,000 and 25,000 pounds. The first one built, after having been delivered to the owner and receiving further modifications, weighed 44,000 pounds with the tanks mostly empty. I'm guessing it wouldn't have stayed afloat. The hardest part of making a boat have positive floatation is accepting what the boat can really weigh, and accepting the weight and volume of floatation chambers needed to accommodate the weight. If I want to add 200 pounds of anchors and 400 pounds of anchor chain to a boat, how much buoyancy space and foam weight needs to be added along with it? It gets ugly fast.
